# Select element by chance from MYSQL

Tags: php

Hello im trying to make a script where it choice random column from table, but based on chances. My table looks likt that:

```
ID | NAME | CHANCE
1   Test     20
2   Test     50

//For now i am generating random column like that:

$item = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `roulette_items` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$item -> execute();
$getInfo = $item -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//But how do i involve chances to this?
//Should i first?
"SELECT `CHANCE` from `roulette_items`"
//and then the math?
```

Comment: `$getInfo` is an array. An array of column names and their data. So pick a random column from the array. See [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Based from your data, I think you mean a random row? Something like `select * from roulette_items order by chance * rand() desc limit 1;` should do the trick.

Comment: @SorinLascu You're a lifesaver! Thanks